# Flex TextInput Control: Search Style rendering

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, textinput

I have a TextInput control which has a search functionality for the people in the system.
It works fine. All I need is to style it in such a way that, it will be having search image on the right, which when clicked, will search. Its actually for look and feel part of the application, which will make the search box look much better.

It is exactly similar behavior implemented in search box embedded in Firefox.

Any solution to this?

Thanks :)

Comment: In the Flex 4 Spark TextInput you can set the skinClass to your own custom TextInputSkin. In the skin you can position the search icon image where you would like using basic layout. In this case anchor the icon to the right edge and set the labelDisplay width to 100%. Then add additional paddingRight to the labelDisplay to prevent the text from overlapping the icon.

Answer (score 2):

Ack, avoid subclassing. Think outside the Box, as it were, and use a Canvas:

```
<mx:Canvas>
    <mx:TextInput change="doSearchFor(event.currentTarget.text)" />
    <mx:Image source="search_icon.png" verticalCenter="0" right="5" />
</mx:Canvas>
```

Then make that a component itself if you want to make it neater. Favour composition over inheritance, in MXML as elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
<mx:HBox>
    <mx:TextInput id     = "txtSearch"/>
    <mx:Image source     = "yourSearchIcon.png" 
              click      = "doSearch()" 
              buttonMode = "true"/>
</mx:HBox>
```

That's all!

Comment: This is what I have right now...
I need the image embedded/included in the search textInput itself, and need to get rid of the search button

Comment: 'll try that
But, can't we render the textinput control to add an image at certain position in the text box?

Comment: @online19 - You'll need to subclass the TextInput object and 1) include and position the image in the UITextField of your TextInput subclass; 2) include code to keep it in the correct place.  If I have some time tomorrow morning, I'll see if I can come up with a postable answer.

Comment: @rhtx - Have you by any chance tried this? I am yet to try that. 've been busy through the week. 'll try this and post it if it works

Answer (score 0):

You could write a subclass of TextInput Class which has as an image for "yourSearchIcon" image such as:

```
[Embed(source='../../libs/graphic_elements.swf#search_ico')]
private var searchIcon:Class;
private var searchImg:Image = new Image();

private function onCreationComplete(event:Event) : void {
    searchImg.source = searchIcon;
    searchImg.x = this.width - 40;
    this.addChild(searchImg);
    this.addEventListener(ResizeEvent.RESIZE, onResize);
}
```

obviously you have to handle the resize event

```
private function onResize(event:ResizeEvent) : void {
        searchImg.x = event.currentTarget.width - 40;

    }
```

That's your custom component

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code will help you. This code adds a search icon to the left of the `TextInput`.

```
public class SearchInputBox extends TextInput
{

[Embed(source='../../../../assets/images/icons/searchIcon.png')]
private var searchIcon:Class;   
private var searchImg:Image;        

override protected function createChildren():void
{
        super.createChildren();
        searchImg = new Image();
        searchImg.source = searchIcon;
        searchImg.width=15;
        searchImg.height=15;
        searchImg.x = 2;
        searchImg.y = 3;

        setStyle("paddingLeft",searchImg.width+2);
        addChild(searchImg);

}
}
```